# Scraping a list of URLs and confirming whether it contains 2 set phrases

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

*This is my second question and it follows on from [yesterdays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44706841/outputting-all-possible-permutations-of-multiple-lists).*

I've attempted to do this both via requests.get and BeautifulSoup without much luck.

**My Goal:**

From my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44706841/outputting-all-possible-permutations-of-multiple-lists) I have a list of strings which I would like to itterate through and append each one to a URL and then scrap that URL to establish whether it contains a two phrases.

**The Phrases**

The phrases I'm looking for is:

- TOYOTA
- SILVER

*(Anything else can be rejected and on with the next URL.)*

**The URL**

The URL is "**https://vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/ConfirmVehicle?Vrm=**" *+ STRING*

**Examples**

1. https://vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/ConfirmVehicle?Vrm=CV05LWT
2. https://vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/ConfirmVehicle?Vrm=CV05LWX
3. https://vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/ConfirmVehicle?Vrm=CV05LWY

**The HTML**

```
<ul class="list-summary margin-bottom-2">
  <li class="list-summary-item">
    <span>Registration number</span>
    <span class="reg-mark">CV05 LWT</span>
  </li>
  <li class="list-summary-item">
    <span>Make</span>
    <span><strong>TOYOTA</strong></span>
  </li>
  <li class="list-summary-item">
    <span>Colour</span>
    <span><strong>SILVER</strong></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Final Steps**

Any URLs which have the two phrases would need the original string (*e.g. CV05LWT*) to be copied into a new list for further processing at a later date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we summon up with your [yersterday's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44706841/outputting-all-possible-permutations-of-multiple-lists) you can perform your web scraping problem with the following code:

```
import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import lxml.html
import re
import itertools

List1 = ['CA', 'CB', 'CC', 'CD', 'CE', 'CF', 'CG', 'CH', 'CJ', 'CK', 'CL', 'CM', 'CN', 'CO', 'CP', 'CR', 'CS', 'CT', 'CU', 'CV', 'CW', 'CX', 'CY']
List2 = ['51', '02', '52', '03', '53', '04', '54', '05', '55', '06', '56', '07', '57', '08', '58', '09', '59', '10', '60', '11', '61', '12', '62', '13', '63', '14', '64', '15', '65', '16', '66', '17']
List3 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
List4 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
List5 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
s = [List1, List2, List3, List4, List5]
marks = list(itertools.product(*s))

for mark in marks:
    mark = "".join(mark)
    url = "https://vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/ConfirmVehicle?Vrm=" + mark
    print "Checking " + mark + "..."

    result = requests.get(url)

    marks_match = list()

    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(result.content)
    html = soup.findAll("li", "list-summary-item")

    if len(html) == 3:
        make = lxml.html.document_fromstring(str(html[1])).text_content()
        make = re.findall(r'\n.*\n(.*)',make)[0]

        colour = lxml.html.document_fromstring(str(html[2])).text_content()
        colour = re.findall(r'\n.*\n(.*)',colour)[0]

        if make == "TOYOTA" and colour == "SILVER":
            marks_match.append(mark)
            print mark + " is TOYOTA SILVER"

print "TOYOTA SILVER cars: " + str(marks_match)
```

The list `marks_match` will have the registration numbers you are looking for.

Of course it will take a while to finish.

Comment: Thanks Cedric, exactly what I was after. Thank you very much for taking the time to copy the code for question1 too.

Comment: Glad to know it works as you expected :) It is indeed an interesting problem the one you posted.

Comment: Hi Cedrix. I've tried this script but something didn't work as expected. It had outputted on the console Matches (including No Matches) but once it had gone through all the permatations, it restarted from scratch and so I wasn't able to output (and save) all the matches. Do you think it might be better to output the matching entries into a file?

Comment: Hi @ZanderG . Writing the output to a file would be a good choice. You can use `f=open("output.txt","a")` and then write what you want like `f.write(mark + " is TOYOTA SILVER\n")` and `f.write("TOYOTA SILVER cars: " + str(marks_match) + "\n")`

Answer (score 0):

Using BeautifulSoup you will have to inspect the element of the page that you want to capture. For you, when you reach "Pattern C", a sucessful result, you then need to check if the make and color are correct. Without seeing your code, I cant properly add to it, but here's an example of how it should look...

```
Make = BeautifulSoup(subreq.text).find('td', id = 'Make')
Colour = BeautifulSoup(subreq.text).find('td', id = 'Colour')

if (Tag Found)
   if (Color == "color you need") && (Make == "Make you need")
       Add to list
else
   Move to the next Tag
```

Comment: Thank you Trent. I appreciate that you've taken the time to type that up without any of my contribution in terms of the code I've hacked together. I'll have some time over the weekend to give your suggestion a go and respond. I guess I wouldn't even need to bother checking for Pattern A & B if all I'm after is the matching of a string for Pattern C as you've pointed out.

Comment: Hi Trent, I've changed the question, removed alot of the nonesense and added some of the targeted HTML that I'm looking to match against.